# How to get products category ID in opencart 2?

Tags: opencart2.x

I want to get same category products. I can get category ID from the path in the case if the path is like:

```
index.php?route=product/product&path=424_429&product_id=3491
```

But when I get product page through search, the path is look like:

```
index.php?route=product/product&product_id=3491&search=96-020-301&description=true
```

so I have product ID, but how can I get products category ID?

Comment: Simply different category can have same product,

Comment: any luck finding an answer?